# Python validation API

Tags: java, python, validation, domain-driven-design, bean-validation

I'm looking for a Python (<3) validation API  something like Java's [Bean Validation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) or [Spring validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator). I'm not looking for a library that is limited to form validation, since I want to validate domain objects.

Do you know a Python API for validating of domain objects?

Comment: Is the <3 restricting the possible answer options? I was also looking for something to make an empty-string-check a bit neater and more developer-friendly, and even 13 years on, it doesn't look like there's anything there yet :-/

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should try [formencode](http://formencode.org/)? it's not form-only validation library

Comment: However formencode is sometimes html-centric (e.g. multiple error messages might be concatenated by '<br>' into a single string). Also formencode has some weird naming in some cases (overwrite '_process', inherit from FancyValidator) and very weak unit-testing. That's why I created [pycerberus](http://www.schwarz.eu/opensource/projects/pycerberus).

Answer (score 2):

[Spring.py](http://springpython.webfactional.com/)

Comment: I not a big fan of Spring, even in the Java land. But Spring in Python sounds not like a good idea to me.

Comment: Your opinion, nothing more.  Whether you like it or not, it does offer validation services that don't depend on HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

The only libraries that are a bit like Java's Bean validation that I know (and have used) are:

- Zope 3's [zope.schema](http://docs.zope.org/zope.schema/) , but this is tied to using zope interfaces I think
- SQLAlchamy's [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki), but this is tied to using SQLAlchemy entities

I'm not sure if (or how) these could be used without depending of specific super classes

Answer (score 1):

+1 for [formencode](http://formencode.org) and also there is promising [pycerberus](http://www.schwarz.eu/opensource/projects/pycerberus) .